# phpmyadmin is not impoting table with large size

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I m using ubuntu server with virtualmin and phpmyadmin.i make all changes in php.ini file related to import table size in phpmyadmin and it is ok , but when i import table that contain more rows in openspeedsheet file from excel it is just loading loading and loading dose not import the table.
My table contain 2050 rows and 8 columns.

Comment: How big is your file? Did you restart your webserver after changing the filesize setting?

Comment: Yes and file size is 108kb